# Cursor does not change to pointer on link hover in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a couple of links on a page. In all browsers except for Safari, the cursor changes to a pointer when hovering on a link. I'm not sure what's happening with Safari. All links are functional and all other CSS and HTML loads, only the cursor is not working.

CSS

```
.social-icons
  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
  }
  .social-icons .svg
  {
        color: #6a567f;
    line-height: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 20px 14px;
  }

 .splash .social-icons .svg:hover .st0
  {
      fill:#ffffff;
      cursor:pointer;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="social-icons"><a class="fbn" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img class="svg" src="fb.svg"/></a><a href="http://twitter.com"><img class="svg" src="twitter.svg"/></a><a href="http://www.tumblr.com"><img class="svg" src="tumblr.svg"/></a><a href="http://instagram.com"><img class="svg" src="ig.svg"/></a></div>
```

Note: .st0 is the class for each svg path.

Answer (score 0):

- You can either remove `st0` from the selector:

Like this:

```
.social-icons .svg:hover {
    fill: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

- Or, if you need to add/use the `st0` class, add it to the img html element and to the css selector:

HTML:

```
<img class="svg st0" src="ig.svg" />
```

CSS:

```
.social-icons .svg:hover.st0 {
    fill: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Snippet with 1st option:

```css
.social-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.social-icons .svg {
  color: #6a567f;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px 14px;
}

.social-icons .svg:hover {
  fill: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icons">
  <a class="fbn" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img class="svg" src="fb.svg" /></a>
  <a href="http://twitter.com"><img class="svg" src="twitter.svg" /></a>
  <a href="http://www.tumblr.com"><img class="svg" src="tumblr.svg" /></a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com"><img class="svg" src="ig.svg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Within the <svg> tag is <path> with the class st0 that we can't remove, if that helps.

Comment: Oh I see, well in that case impact the `.svg` class directly, it's working fine on the snippet. `.social-icons .svg:hover {cursor:pointer;}` the `:hover` should be done on either the `<img>` or `<a>` elements not path. The `.svg` would be the `<img>`. The other thing that could be happening, it's maybe something you haven't shared in your code is overriding it.